# Determining Millisecond Time Intervals In Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, time

Just as background, I'm building an application in Cocoa.  This application existed originally in C++ in another environment.  I'd like to do as much as possible in Objective-C.

My questions are:

1)
How do I compute, as an integer, the number of milliseconds between now and the previous time I remembered as now?

2)
When used in an objective-C program, including time.h, what are the units of

clock()

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()`](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTimeUtils/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001452-CH201-F12326) but bear in mind the clock can change between two calls and can screw you over. If you want to protect against that you should use [`CACurrentMediaTime()`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CACurrentMediaTime).

The return type of these is `CFAbsoluteTime` and `CFTimeInterval` respectively, which are both `double` by default. So they return the number of seconds with `double` precision. If you *really* want an integer you can use `mach_absolute_time()` found in `#include <mach/mach_time.h>` which returns a 64 bit integer. This needs a bit of unit conversion, so check out [this link](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2004/qa1398.html) for example code. This is what `CACurrentMediaTime()` uses internally so it's probably best to stick with that.

Computing the difference between two calls is obviously just a subtraction, use a variable to remember the last value.

For the `clock` function see the documentation here: [clock()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/). Basically you need to divide the return value by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` to get the actual time.

Comment: Non-C++-specific doc link for `clock`: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/clock.3.html

Answer (score 6):

> How do I compute, as an integer, the number of milliseconds between now and the previous time I remembered as now?

Is there any reason you need it as an integral number of milliseconds? Asking NSDate for the time interval since another date will give you a floating-point number of seconds. If you really do need milliseconds, you can simply multiply by that by 1000 to get a floating-point number of milliseconds. If you really do need an integer, you can round or truncate the floating-point value.

If you'd like to do it with integers from start to finish, use either `UpTime` or `mach_absolute_time` to get the current time in absolute units, then use `AbsoluteToNanoseconds` to convert that to a real-world unit. Obviously, you'll have to divide that by 1,000,000 to get milliseconds.

[QA1398](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2004/qa1398.html) suggests `mach_absolute_time`, but `UpTime` is easier, since it returns the same type `AbsoluteToNanoseconds` uses (no “pointer fun” as shown in the technote).

`AbsoluteToNanoseconds` returns an `UnsignedWide`, which is a structure. (This stuff dates back to before Mac machines could handle scalar 64-bit values.) Use the `UnsignedWideToUInt64` function to convert it to a scalar. That just leaves the subtraction, which you'll do the normal way.